# How to access parent form functions?

Tags: c#, winforms

Am trying to access the parent form functions (methods). Even by using static keyword it is not working.

The parent form is of type (MDI) and has normal child form. This is C# Application. Am trying use this way to access the methods , but no advance !

```
this.MdiParent
```

Please help me !

Comment: Have you tried casting `this.MdiParent` to the type of the parent form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you declared static methods, then you should call them via parent form's class name:

```
YourParentFormType.YourStaticMethod();
```

If you want to use instance methods, then you should declare them as `public` and call via casting MDI parent reference:

```
((YourParentFormType)this.MdiParent).YourInstanceMethod();
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to cast `this.MdiParent` to the right type.

If your parent form is of type `MyForm`, use

```
 ((MyForm)this.MdiParent).MyMethod();
```

Same for static methods: Call them through the right type

```
MyForm.MyStaticMethod();
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working. I mean only the native methods allowed not the user-defined ones for the first case (not-static)

Comment: @Hatem What do you mean with *not working* while accepting an answer that is exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

this.MdiParent returns the instance of type Form

This means it will only show functions that are definedin the Form class definition.

In order to reach other methods, you need to cast it to the class type that implaments the Form, e.g.

((MyForm)Form).MyFunction()

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can be accessed by using `Type.Method()`.

If you want to accesse an instance method you need to cast the `MdiParent` to the correct type.

```
MyParentType parent = (MyParentType)this.MdiParent;
parent.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working. I mean only the native methods allowed not the user-defined ones.

Comment: What is different between these lines and the accepted answer? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`MdiParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx) property of the form when you create it:

```
// Make the new form a child form.
child.MdiParent = this;
// Display the child form.
child.Show();
```

Then you can access the parent form.  If you just want Form properties you don;t need to cast:

```
Form parent = this.MdIParent;
string parentTitle = parent.Text;
```

If you need to access cusotm properties/methoids just cast it to the right type:

```
ParentForm parent = this.MdIParent as ParentForm;   // using your own type name of course
string title = parent.MyStringProperty;
```